# OnReadyStateComplete is not fired

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I try to add CRM javascript web resource and try to manage iframe elements, but iframe OnReadyStateComplete event is not fired. Below, the first alert works but the second does not.

```
function hello()
    {
        var audioPath= Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_audiopath").getValue();
         //var myAudio = document.createElement('audio');
         //myAudio.setAttribute('src', audioPath);
         // myAudio.play(); 

            var IFrame = Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("IFRAME_Play");
            alert(audioPath);
            //var myAudio =Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("audioSource");

          IFrame.OnReadyStateComplete=function(){
          alert('iframe ready');
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem, but only with iframe content from other domians. I think it's the security restrictions, not allowing to raise events.
We worked around it with a aspx-page on the server, which downloaded the content, and recreated it for the xrm script.

Comment: http://sadi:8090/play.aspx  ---> iframe url                                                                                                                                  http://sadi:5555/                 ---> dynamics crm url                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              They are in the same domain.

Comment: The issue here is that the event is not fired. I doubt this has anything to do with XSS, because in the sample above there is no scripting code trying to access the document in the containing window.

Answer (score 1):

The IFrame control does not have an `OnReadyStateComplete` property or event. The SDK documentation only hints at the menu-option that is available in the form designer.

However, it is actually possible to attach a function to the `onload` event of the IFrame in a supported way:

```
var iFrameElement = Xrm.Page.getControl("IFRAME_Play").getObject();
iFrameElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
    alert("IFrame Play loaded!");
}
```

Function `getObject` returns an IFrame object giving you access to the iFrame's window and the document it contains through its `contentWindow` and `contentDocument` properties. (See also [HTML DOM IFrame Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp).)